# Can we send media or files from WhatsApp click to chat?

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I am able to send text messages and links with WhatsApp click to chat.

I've researched a lot about this but I'm unable to figure out how to send pdf or other media as messages to people with WhatsApp click to chat.

https://wa.me/44XXXXXXXXXX?text=Hello%World

I've seen this implementation in an app. The app makes pdf of the context and redirects to the WhatsApp app and opens a specific contact with that pdf attached.

But I am not sure that whether that app is using some kind of api or not.

I just wanted to know from experts that is it possible to send media files/ documents with WhatsApp click to chat?

https://wa.me/44XXXXXXXXXX?text=Hello%World?data=...

https://wa.me/44XXXXXXXXXX?text=Hello%World?image=...

??

Comment: What is WhatsApp click?

Comment: the link which can instantly start a chat with any number available on WhatsApp.

Comment: Where do you see that link?

Comment: https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934 - this will help

Comment: Does not help as we do not follow links. Just answer.

Comment: From what I read, I think it would be better for you to specify more, why would you like to send this PDF file via WhatsApp? How is this PDF generated and why should it be delivered to recipient of "click to chat"?

Comment: I am generating a ticket from my website. The website will  take its screen shot and then I wanted to send this image or pdf with WhatsApp click to chat feature.

Answer (score 1):

No, only text is supported.

Learn more: https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934